# How to make an object have a clay like surface?

Tags: modeling, materials, sculpting

I am new to blender and I am trying to add a clay like material to an object in blender.
I tried using a material but I want the object to have a rough imperfect dull surface like play-doh. Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: Are you using Blender Internal renderer or Cycles?

Comment: By the way, clay materials and "play-doh" materials are different.

Comment: I am using Blender internal render

Answer (score 2):

For a clay material, simply set the *Specularity* to 0:

[image: Specular light disabled in Blender Internal]
[image: Clay render in Blender Internal]

If you want it to be more like "play-doh" you might want to raise the specular lighting by a bit (maybe to 0.1), but it will also be important to actually deform the model some. [Play-doh shapes](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_sw09_UT9jqE/TJFSht9JXGI/AAAAAAAADfU/aWleXUXsC1w/008_thumb%5B2%5D.jpg?imgmax=800) aren't perfectly smooth. I find that using a *Voronoi texture* on a *Displace* modifier, followed by a *Cast to Sphere*, works pretty well. Here's an exaggerated image and a more realistic image:

[image: Exaggerated displacement]
[image: More realistic displacement]

Finally, here's the modifiers and texture setup I used:

[image: Modifier setup]
[image: Texture setup]

Comment: this works but it tends to deform my objects i already made

Comment: @user2883800 Yes. That's the point. That's why I said that it's "important to actually deform the model some." Sometimes appearances are about more than just materials. If you don't want to deform at all just don't include *Cast* or *Displace*; if you want a different method, try a bump map.

Comment: I found another way to create a clay surface and it is working well. Thank you for your help though.