# How to make a Stone/Clay Material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I want to make a clay material like in this photo. **Not a clay render**, a **clay material**; something for my sculptures I model in Blender. How could I make something like the material in this image?

[image]

I have been trying to make this material for hours and it's driving me crazy.
please help!

this is what i have gotten after playing around with nodes:

[image]

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far? Might be a better learning experience for you if someone points out your mistakes rather than just present you with a final solution.

Comment: Yep, this site is more geared towards helping solve a problem, rather than making it for you.

Comment: a clay render is not at all what i need. for better understanding i edited the question.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4938/how-to-make-an-object-have-a-clay-like-surface

Comment: no, again not a white/blank material or play-doh. CLAY, look at the picture. see the texture/material on him? i want to replicate that..

Comment: cegatron, please un-mark this as a duplicate. it is not

Comment: @Optimus I agree with you that this is not a duplicate of the marked question. However, my suggestion stands, show what you have tried so far. I.e. screenshots of node setups you've tried and/or how your scene is lit. I'm sure a lot of people here can replicate the material from your image, but just giving you a ready made solution is counter productive, as it doesn't teach you a lot and it will be less useful to others.

Comment: Here is mine for a clay material like **_this_**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWjJfw32cbM

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using textures to add some subtle displacement and/or normal mapping. Box mapped image textures or procedural textures are perfect for this. For example, here's a simple procedural texture consisting of some high frequency details mixed with a few larger features, normal mapped onto a diffuse shader (plus a touch of displacement):

[image]

[image]

It may be helpful to throw in some image textures to get some more irregular larger-scale features.

Note that true displacement is required to get those tasty bits of self-shadowing near the terminators prevalent in your example. Displacement is still currently an experimental feature, so to use it you'll have to switch enable experimental features in *Properties > Render > Feature Set*. Once that's done, be sure to set the displacement method to *True* in the material settings.

Displacement means the actual geometry is being displaced, so for it to work you need a sufficiently dense mesh. Adaptive subdivision is ideal for this; to enable it, add a subsurf modifier and enable *Adaptive* under *Render*.

See [Blender Cycles True Displacement](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45873/599) for more details.

---

Also keep in mind that lighting is just as (or perhaps even more) important as the material itself. Part of what makes your example distinctive is the long light-to-shadow transitions which show off the fine details of the material.

Try playing around with lights and different lighting setups while making the material to get a sense of how it behaves under different conditions.